# Проблема с кодировкой у FireFox

Tags: кодировка, firefox, браузер

Здравствуйте!
Есть сайт http://178.86.13.88/setup/register.php
Кодировка в FireFox кривая, у всех остальных браузерах нормально.
Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В заголовке четко приходит:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Укажите явно

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Если это ваш сайт, то отправить правильную кодировку использовав .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```